# Remove quotes from specif value in array json, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, json

I have this code

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "assets/js/calendar-data.php",
        data:{data: $(dataString).serializeArray()}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(data){
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
            demodata = json;

        }
    });
```

and I get the data like this

```
Object { title="Networking",  start ="new Date(y, m, d, 20, 0)",  end ="new Date(y, m, d, 21, 0)", content= "Test content" }
```

But I want to remove the double quotes from the start and end value, not from all the values only from that.

Correct output:

```
Object { title="Networking",  start =new Date(y, m, d, 20, 0),  end =new Date(y, m, d, 21, 0), content= "Test content" }
```

Can you help me with that?

Comment: It the object being sent or received?

Comment: i receive this object so i must do it in js file...

Comment: You need to convert this to something that JavaScript can use. Try:  eval( Obj.start)

Comment: can you help me with some code or example because i can't fix it...

Comment: So, you want the `"new Date(...)"` to become actual `Date` objects?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `eval`.  Be very careful with that and always sanitize the data.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute a string in javascript, you'd want to use the global `eval` function.

```
eval(demodata.start)
```

Its noteworthy to mention that not only is eval very slow, its also rather [dangerous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!), so use at your own risk